# Working with Map, Sum, mean using loadash

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## Background

I've the following data set with me

```
let animals = 
[
  {id:1, attributes:[{ title:'cat',score:3, weight:30 }]},
  {id:2, attributes:[{ title:'cat',score:4, weight:22 }]},
  {id:3, attributes:[{ title:'dog',score:5, weight:26 }]}
  {id:4, attributes:[{ title:'dog',score:5, weight:22 }]}

]
```

My requirement is to make this look like this:

```
let animals = 
[
  { animal:'cat',avg_score:3.5, avg_weight:26 },
  { animal:'dog',avg_score:5, avg_weight:24 } 
]
```

Where the avg_score and avg_weight should be the average of the score and weight for the respective title.

Reading the documentation of loadash, I was able to figure out that,

1. We need to use _.groupBy() function to group by title
2. we need to use _mean() function to take the average

I'm unable to figure out how to get this done together. What I tried so far-

```
    const answer = _( animals )
        .groupBy( 'attributes.title' )
        .map( () => ( {
            title: attributes.title,
                        score: _.mean(attribute.score),
                        weight: _.mean(attribute.weight),
        } ) )
        .value();

    console.log( "Master Data : " + answer );
```

However, since the title, score, and weight are child items and we need some kind of a loop to iterate and get the corresponding row's entity, i'm unable to process further. Example, the assignment should be something like `'title' : row.attributes.title` where row is reference of the iteration coming form the loop.
Can someone please help out to unfold this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With plain ES6:

For each animal entry, use reduce to keep a running total of score, weight, and count. Then calculate the averages as total/count.

```js
const animals = [{"id":1,"attributes":[{"title":"cat","score":3,"weight":30}]},{"id":2,"attributes":[{"title":"cat","score":4,"weight":22}]},{"id":3,"attributes":[{"title":"dog","score":5,"weight":26}]},{"id":4,"attributes":[{"title":"dog","score":5,"weight":22}]}]

const r = Object.values(animals.reduce((a,
  {attributes:[{title,score,weight}]},o)=>(
    o=(a[title]??={animal:title, count:0, totalScore:0, totalWeight:0}),
    o.count++, o.totalScore+=score, o.totalWeight+=weight, a),{}))
  .map(({animal,count,totalScore,totalWeight})=>
    ({animal, avg_score:totalScore/count, avg_weight:totalWeight/count}))

console.log(r)
```